# URL rewriting in PHP using .htaccess: How to put `/` in URL?

Tags: .htaccess, parameter-passing

I have a URL like `www.test.com?id=other-flavor&pid=hannycakes`.

I did above URL like `www.test.com/other-flavor$pid=hannycakes` using `.Htaccess` 
but I need `www.test.com/other-flavor/hannycakes`.

For this If I use `/` in my URL it can take as a folder.
How resolve my problem. How to put `/` in URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?id=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```